# Access only one element of a pair in an unordered_map in c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, unordered-map, value-type

I'm trying to get the same behavior as a rust tuple destructuring in C++.
For example: I have an unordered_map I want to iterate over. However, The only data that I care about are the values, and not keys.

Is there a way to iterate over it with a for loop without using the following syntax ? (which is what I have for now)

```
for (auto &pair : _map)
{
   std::cout << pair.second << std::endl;
}
```

I would want to get something like this:

```
for (auto &value : _map)
{
   std::cout << value << std::endl; // This would give me the value and not a pair with key and value.
}
```

Comment: Is having to write `.second` really that big a deal?

Comment: @tadman in many other languages you can either iterate over keys and values, so it would be nice to do this in c++ too

Comment: range-v3 has `views::keys`, and `views::values`.

Comment: Using structure bindings https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Comment: @tadman no it's not, but in my case it leads to a lot of redundant code, that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: @RichardCritten I find that to be painful, because of having to suppress unused variable warnings.

Comment: I get that, but the short answer is "Deal with it". The long answer is that doing transformations to make your life more convenient is inefficient. C++ is used to write fast code, not necessarily fun to write code. Other languages offer significantly more conveniences, like Rust, or even better, Ruby, but they often do this at the expense of speed.

Comment: @tadman then you could say this to the user, and why you cant do this in c++, not be rude to me or the OP.

Comment: @tadman Ok ! Thanks for your answer !

Comment: @RichardCritten That's what I was searching for. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your compiler supports the C++ 17 Standard then you can write something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::string> m =
    {
        { 1, "first" },
        { 2, "second" }
    };

    for ( const auto &[key, value] : m )
    {        
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
second first
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the range-v3 library, you can iterate over keys:

```
for (auto key : m | views::keys)
  // use key
```

or over values:

```
for (auto value : m | views::values)
  // use value
```

where `m` can be a `map`.

In c++17, you could do:

```
for ([[maybe_unused]] auto [key, value] : m)
  // use key or value
```

Note that the attribute `[[maybe_unused]]` is used to suppress the warnings about not using one of the variables.